# Stars corresponding to the dropdown in Star Rating jQuery Plugin don't show up in case of dynamically generated data

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jquery

I'm using [Chris Richards' Star Rating jQuery Plugin from Github](https://github.com/ripter/jquery.rating) alongwith the [jQuery Template plugin](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2010/10/05/jquery-templates-on-microsoft-ajax-cdn.aspx). When the data is inline, the rating control works fine. See [sample](http://jsbin.com/exuxo4) & [source](http://jsbin.com/exuxo4/edit).

However, when the rating control is used with dynamically generated data, the star image doesn't get applied through the CSS to the dropdown control that internally handles the rating. See [sample](http://jsbin.com/adije) (click on buttons there) & [source](http://jsbin.com/adije/edit).

The alert that I have set to the rating control works though. What can be done to make the stars show up instead of the dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to call `$(".rating").rating();` after the dynamic content load is complete.

Modify your `getJSON` code:

```
$("#flickr").live("click", function() {
  var url = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/groups_pool.gne?id=44124373027@N01&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?";
  // Grab some flickr images of cats
  $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    // Format the data using the catTemplate
    $("#result").empty().append("");
    $("#catTemplate").tmpl(data.items).appendTo("#result");
    // set up rating plugin
    $(".rating").rating();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I modified my code as you suggested but the stars don't show up & the dropdown doesn't appear as well. Can you please check the source & tell me what I'm missing - http://jsbin.com/adije/4/edit

Comment: @mvark The line below `<style type="text/css" media="screen">` is a typo/error. You are missing the class for the CSS. Here's a corrected one: http://jsbin.com/adije/5/edit

Comment: That's an embarrassing mistake. Thanks for taking the time to identify it & making my sample work.